# Jenkins Fail Downstream Jobs After Failure

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm in the need to Fail all the Downstream Jobs after a Failure in the Father Job.

Let's say I have

```
Job A -> Job B -> Job C
```

Where a Downstream Job is Run Only if the Upstream Succeeds.

I need:

- to Fail B and C if A Fails
- to Fail C if B Fails

I didn't find a suitable plugin to achieve this result, maybe somebody with the same need found a way?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do — if a build of job A fails, no builds of job B or C will be executed. You can't mark a *job* as failed, only a *build*, but in this case there would be no (new) builds of jobs B or C once the build of job A completes.

Comment: I understand... so after a failure in A there's no other way than trigger a new build on B and then C and just add a check in both B and C that the upstream job succeeded or otherwise fail the build

Comment: I would try to do it like that. But maybe there is a more elegant solution. JobDSL?

Answer (score 1):

Since it is possible to trigger job B and / or C as a downstream from A even A was failed - determine the A status and create a variable that will determine if job B or C should be run ( like RUN=1 for do_run ). Then add a parameter to downstream jobs and check the variable in the beginning of job B or C.

Wouldn't it be better to not run B or C at all when A fails? Don't know what you are trying to do, but just suggesting.

Comment: The thing here is that some people don't watch to the result of the upstream but only of the downstream and they see a green thinking that it's OK which is not.